# Cypher recommendation query taking too long

Tags: cypher

I have a Neo4j query that has to return up to the 20 companies with the most number of investments made from co-investors of the given investor.

I have two types of nodes, Objects (That represents investors and companies), and FundingRound. It's indexes by `objects.id` and `funding_round.id`.

This is the query:

```
MATCH
  (me:Object {id: $investorId})-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(mycompany:Object)
MATCH
  (coinvestor:Object)-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(mycompany)
MATCH
  (coinvestor)-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(othercompany:Object)
WITH me, othercompany, COUNT(distinct coinvestor) AS matches_count
WHERE NOT (me)-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(othercompany)
RETURN othercompany.id AS id, othercompany.name AS name, matches_count
ORDER BY matches_count DESC, othercompany.id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

The query sometimes tasks up to 7 seconds to run for investors with a lot of investments. So I'm wondering, is there something that is not optimized correctly?

Profiling it in Neo4j app show it had 14601993 total db hits but the steps make total sense. I hoped it had a better performance when I read https://neo4j.com/news/how-much-faster-is-a-graph-database-really/

Comment: So basically you are trying to recommend what other companies your coinvestors have invested in?

Comment: @TomažBratanič exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
MATCH
  (me:Object {id: $investorId})-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(mycompany:Object),
  (coinvestor:Object)-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(mycompany)
WITH collect(distinct coinvestor) AS coinvestors, collect(distinct mycompany) AS mycompanies
UNWIND coinvestors AS coinvestor
MATCH
  (coinvestor)-[:INVESTED_IN]->(:FundingRound)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(othercompany:Object)
WHERE NOT othercompany IN mycompanies
WITH othercompany, COUNT(distinct coinvestor) AS matches_count
ORDER BY matches_count DESC, othercompany.id ASC
LIMIT 20
RETURN othercompany.id AS id, othercompany.name AS name, matches_count
```

It should be a bit of improvement as we don't do a couple of redundant operations. However, it might still take some time if there are a lot of coinvestors and other companies, since Neo4j is known to have some issues with ordering large number of rows.

If your graph model allows, I would also remove node labels in the query. If, for example, the *INVESTED_IN* relation can only point from an object to a funding round, we don't have to check the node label for it.

Comment: OMFG you are a god, thank you!! The load tests average 73ms for your query, when it was averaging up to 2second for my original version. I could even make it more performant by taking your idea further and adding distinct to the mycompanies, could you update your comment with that code and I accept it